# Media query in d3.js only partially successful

Tags: d3.js, svg

I want to resize a d3.js chart using media queries, and apply transitions.  The graph setup in html is:

```
<g id="d3js_graph">
<svg class="d3svg"></svg>
<script src="JS\D3_BarChart.js"></script>
</g>
```

I applied a media query to the d3svg class and used a transform:

```
@media (min-width: 1080px) {
  .d3svg {
    transform: translate(-30px,-30px); }
}
```

That works to move the graph, but now the graph shows with the left half blanked out, which implies that the graph but not its container have been moved.  So I reversed it and applied the media query to the  d3js_graph ID (in the opening g tag above):

```
@media (min-width: 1080px) {
  #d3js_graph {
    transform: translate(-30px,-30px); }
}
```

But that does nothing, so that’s not the element.  It’s the .d3svg class shown above.  I could use a transition in the d3.js file:

d3.select("body").transition().style("color", "red");

but how to I do d3.select within a media query in the d3.js file?  I added a media query in the file, but it simply caused the graph to disappear from the screen.

So my question is:  why is the graph partially blanked out on the left side when I move it using a transform?  What’s the controlling element for a media query on d3.js?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
<g id="d3js_graph">
<svg class="d3svg"></svg>
<script src="JS\D3_BarChart.js"></script>
</g>
```

... is invalid. `<g>` elements are [SVG elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g), and can only be used inside SVGs.

What you want is an HTML `<div>`:

```
<div id="d3js_graph">
<svg class="d3svg"></svg>
<script src="JS\D3_BarChart.js"></script>
</div>
```

Also, I'd consider moving that `<script>` to outside the div.